# Weird formatting in a smaller created empty set symbol

Tags: symbols, typography, kerning

A while back I created my own sort of emptyset symbol because the "not equal" slash didn't line up and it annoyed me. So I defined my own emptyset via `\DeclareMathOperator{\vempty}{{\centernot{\Circle}}}`. However, when I try to use it in a subscript (as demonstrated below), the slash becomes unaligned with the circle. Does anyone know how to remedy this? Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,centernot,cases}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\DeclareMathOperator{\vempty}{{\centernot{\Circle}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\vempty}{{\text{\O}}}

\begin{document}
Example of difference between emptyset, varnothing, and vempty:
    \begin{equation*}
        \neq \emptyset \quad \neq \varnothing \quad \neq \vempty
    \end{equation*}

Example of pathological behavior:
    \begin{equation*}
        \int_{\varnothing} f dm \quad \int_{\vempty} f dm
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Symbols from `wasysym` are defined as

```
\mbox{\wasyfamily\symbol{<number>}}
```

so they don't change size in subscripts. Add `\text` around it.

Oh, and it's not an operator, but an ordinary symbol.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,centernot,cases}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand{\vempty}{{\centernot{\text{\Circle}}}}

\begin{document}

Example of difference between emptyset, varnothing, and vempty:
\begin{equation*}
\neq \emptyset \quad \neq \varnothing \quad \neq \vempty
\end{equation*}

It's horrible also in subscripts \texttt{;-)}
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\varnothing} f dm \quad \int_{\vempty} f\,dm
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Personal note: I consider `\varnothing` a symbol good for plumbers. Your variation is even uglier. `;-)`

Comment: Is there a way to create a symbol which is more aesthetic and has the same slash angle as `\neq`? I tried, for example, `\centernot{0}`, but the slash was misaligned inside of the zero.